# FireFox and SharePoint 2013 authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I set up sharePoint 2013 web application I use this line of script

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName -HostNameAlias spdev.dev.com -Name portal -ZoneName dev.com
```

- spdev - name of pc
- dev.com - domain
- portal - site adress

now I have 2 sites

- CA - http:/spdev:8080
- Team site - http:/portal

If I use IE all works fine, but in firefox I cannot log in to the team site. I see authentication form, I put correct credentials, then click log in button and see authentication form again.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me.  I had made all of the usual *disable loopback check* setting changes in the registry, or so I thought.

I had HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0\BackConnectionHostNames set to include (one per line):

```
intranet.spdev.local
my.spdev.local
```

IE authentication to the host header-enabled sites worked, but Firefox kept prompting me for credentials over and over.  Once I changed that setting to

```
intranet.spdev.local
my.spdev.local
intranet
my
```

Firefox authentication started working fine.  So it appears that IE needs the fully qualified domain name, and Firefox likes just the host header name.  For the *disable loopback check* settings instructions, look [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx).

Comment: it wont work for my shp foundation 2013 and Firefox 55 I spend whole day changing settings for ntlm in ff and dosent work at all

Answer (score 0):

Can you possibly enable NTLM authentication with Firefox core configuration. You can give [this article](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Firefox%20asks%20for%20user%20name%20and%20password%20on%20internal%20sites) a try.

It should work.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work in my case (